# Are the words 'empirical' and 'experimental' interchangeable?

Tags: vocabulary

Are the two words interchangeable in the academia, specifically in the field of physics and engineering?

I am currently reviewing an engineering paper, and the author has used the word '*experimentally*' in a context where I would personally use the word '*empirically*':

**Simulation parameters are set experimentally.**

Naturally, I've tried searching on Google, and I've found a [published book](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/distributed/E/bo10600428.html) that uses both the words '*empirical*' and '*experimental*' in the title. This got me into thinking that the two words have different connotative definitions.

Comment: Vocabulary: think ***dictionary*** :-) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/empirical ...lots of overlap ...http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/experimental but not exactly interchangeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empirical is often referential and is not necessarily done by the author.  For example, 'Test power during shift can increase by a factor of 3 [1].'.  This is empirical data, but the work is done in another paper cited in [1].  On the other hand, experimental data usually follows a description of the experiment itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think if he says the parameters were set experimentally, that means he did separate experiments to determine their values.  But if they were set empirically, that could mean that he merely adopted convenient values for them, so as to make calculations come out right.  (But I'm not a physicist or engineer.)